# Iterate through two lists of different lengths

Tags: python, list

I have the following two lists:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

ltrs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for x, y in nums, ltrs:
    print(x, y)
```

With the following error

```
c:\Python35\Scripts>python listtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listtest.py", line 5, in <module>
    for x, y in nums, ltrs:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I would like for the output to be:

> 1a, 2b, 3c, 4d, 5, 6, 7, 8

From what I have read the `zip` method will only work if the two lists are the same length, what are my options with lists of different lengths?

Comment: check out [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

Comment: Why not just write your own thing for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` for Python3:

```
import itertools
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
ltrs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
final_list = [''.join([str(c) if isinstance(c, int) else c for c in [i for i in b if i is not None]]) for b in itertools.zip_longest(nums, ltrs)]
```

Output:

```
['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

[`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) is similar to `zip`, but allows you to add a default value (`fillvalue`) to use when the shorter list is exhausted. From there on, it's just some simple manipulations:

```
[''.join([str(c) for c in x]) for x in izip_longest(nums, ltrs, fillvalue='')]
```

Comment: That can be shortened up a bit with f-strings: `[f"{x}{y or ''}" for x, y in itertools.zip_longest(nums, ltrs)]`

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
for x, y in list(itertools.zip_longest(nums,ltrs)):
  print(x, y)
```

Output

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 None
6 None
7 None
8 None
```